# Lumen - Filter some results from all select methods

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have an `expired_at` column in database; that when creating any row, by default will be 5 minutes future of the creation time, and i want exclude rows which their `expired_at` has passed (littler from current time).

For example i have this rows in `games` table:

```
id creator_id created_at            updated_at            expire_at  
1  123456789  2017-04-26 01:13:22   2017-04-26 01:13:22   2017-04-26 01:18:22  
2  234567890  2017-04-26 01:16:06   2017-04-26 01:16:06   2017-04-26 01:21:06
```

And when i fetch all rows with `Game::all()` or `Game::where('condition')` function at time `01:19:30`, row 1 shouldn't be fetched, but row 2 should, because it still not expired.

I don't want to process expire time in target code, but in model code (for example overriding where function in model class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this my the means of a (global) scope.

See also [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes) link.

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope('not_expired', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('expired_at', '>', Carbon::now());
    });
}
```

Global scopes will be applied to all queries except when you disable them specifically.

Disabling them can be done by:

```
Game::withoutGlobalScope('not_expired')->all();
```